# How to determine the number of processes considered by the short-term scheduler for process allocation

Tags: bash, unix, script, task-scheduler, scheduling

My assignment is to write a script displaying the number of processes considered by the short-term scheduler for process allocation (processes currently ready to run) at any given time.

Now, writing the script is not the problem. I am not sure where to find these processes. Hopefully one of you will be able to help.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Are you asking how to get the raw information needed? If so, use the `ps` command.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'top' command in linux/unix. It will display the all linux processes including its status and information.

Comment: Can you provide more detail?  Thanks.